# Recursive search over recursive object

Tags: javascript, typescript, recursion

I have some data that looks like this:

```js
const data = {
  "type": "A",
  "items": [
    {
      "type": "B",
      "tokens": [
        {
          "type": "C"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "B",
      "tokens": {
        "type": "A",
        "items": [
          {
            "type": "B",
            "tokens": [
              {
                "type": "D"
              },
              {
                "type": "A",
                "items": [
                  "..."
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "type": "B",
            "tokens": []
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The logic of the data is as follows

- Objects of type `A` contains the field `items`, that contains only objects of type `B` and must contain at least 1 of them.
- Objects of type `B` contain the `tokens` field, that contains all types except `B`, and must contain at least one of them, for example: `D`, `C` or `A`.
- The `B.tokens` could also contain object `A` which contains another `items` and so on. This could be repeated more than 10 levels deep.
- Both `A.items` and `B.tokens` are of the type `Token[]`.

```js
type Token =
    | Tokens.A
    | Tokens.B
    | Tokens.C

namespace Tokens {
  export interface A {
    type: "A";
    items: Token.B[];
  }
  export interface B {
    type:"B"
    tokens: Token[];
  }
  export interface C {
    type: "C";
    content: string;
  }
}
```

I am trying to obtain an array of all entries inside type `B` that are not type `A`. The type `A` inside `B.tokens` should be recursive checked to find entries inside of `B` that aren't `A` and include an index of the depth.

It would be of great help if someone could help me by indicating an approach to the problem or pseudocode.

Thanks in advance.

---

Update on [@Mulan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/633183/mulan) request `What does the final output look like for the example provided?`

Something like this

```json
{
  "id": 0,
  "collection": [
    {
      "type": "C",
      "content": "BLA",
      "depth": 1
    },
    {
      "type": "D",
      "content": "BLO",
      "depth": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

---

Although [Mulan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70596506/14271633) is much more detailed and accurate than mine, I leave what I had tried at the request of [Dima](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4554883/dima-parzhitsky)

```js
const filterTokens = (tokens: Token[], filtered: Token[] = []): Token[] => {
    for (const token of tokens) {
        if (token.type === "A") {
            filterTokens(token.items, filtered);
        } else if (token.type === "B") {
            filterTokens(token.tokens, filtered);
        } else {
            filtered.push(token);
        }
    }
    return filtered;
}
console.log(filterTokens(data.items));
```

Comment: That's a good description of the question, but the actual question is missing. Do you want to have an algorithm?

Comment: The last paragraph is what I'm trying to achieve. But yes, something like and algorithm or an aproximation to the problem

Comment: In your example, sometimes `tokens` is `[...]` and sometimes it is `{...}`. Is that a typo?

Comment: No, it's just mark that is recursive.

Comment: What does the final output look like for the example provided?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mutual recursion is an effective way to process trees. I'll start with some function `f` that accepts an input `t` and an initial `depth` of `0`. We perform a simple type analysis on `t` and declare how each type of `t` should flatten to an array. In this particular case, `Array` is the only one given special consideration, all other items can be treated as a single item -

```js
const f = (t, depth = 0) => {
  switch (t?.constructor) {
    case Array: return t.flatMap(v => f(v, depth))
    default: return f1(t, depth)
  }
}
```

When we encounter a single item, we pass it to some function `f1` that processes just *one* item. Here we do a type analysis on the nodes `type` property and declare how each type, `A`, `B`, etc, should flatten -

```
const f1 = (t, depth = 0) => {
  switch (t?.type) {
    case "A": return f(t.items, depth + 1)
    case "B": return f(t.tokens, depth + 1)
    default: return [{...t, depth}]
  }
}
```

In your mock data I made a change to keep it consistent with the tree shape -

```js
// ellipses
"..."

// replaced with
{type:"Z",content:"..."}
```

```js
console.log(f(data))
```

```js
[
  {
    "type": "C",
    "depth": 2
  },
  {
    "type": "D",
    "depth": 4
  },
  {
    "type": "Z",
    "content": "...",
    "depth": 5
  }
]
```

Here's a full working demo -

```js
const f = (t, depth = 0) => {
  switch (t?.constructor) {
    case Array: return t.flatMap(v => f(v, depth))
    default: return f1(t, depth)
  }
}

const f1 = (t, depth) => {
  switch (t?.type) {
    case "A": return f(t.items, depth + 1)
    case "B": return f(t.tokens, depth + 1)
    default: return [{...t, depth}]
  }
}

const data =
  {type:"A",items:[{type:"B",tokens:[{type:"C"}]},{type:"B",tokens:{type:"A",items:[{type:"B",tokens:[{type:"D"},{type:"A",items:[{type:"Z",content:"..."}]}]},{type:"B",tokens:[]}]}}]}

console.log(f(data))
```

Comment: This is a better approximation than I had arrived at. Thank you very much for helping me understand the problem better and providing a solution to it